Shared taxonomy for hash, mac and digital signature algorithms and output?
I'm creating a cryptography API, and because naming things is hard, I'm trying to define a common name that identifies functions that accept input of arbitrary length and produce either digital signatures, MACs or hashes.
I've scoured the HAC chapters 1, 9 and 11 for quite a while, but haven't found anything that summarily reflects a single name/synonym that intuitively describes all three without resorting to mathematical names that don't necessarily imply any of them.  Given:

A hash algorithm is an unkeyed one-way collision-resistant function that accepts input of arbitrary length and produces output of a fixed length, called a "hash-code, hash-result, hash-value, or simply hash". (HAC Definitions 9.3 and 9.4)

A MAC algorithm is a keyed hash function that additionally affords "computation-resistance", and its output is called a "mac" or "tag". (HAC Definition 9.7)

A digital signature generation algorithm is a keyed function that associates a message with some originating entity, and its output is called a "signature". (HAC 11.2.1).  For a given signing key, the signature generation function is a 1:1 mapping from message -> signature, and that function is called a signing transformation. (HAC Definition 11.8, §11.2.2 Algorithm 11.4.1, and §11.2.3 Algorithm 11.8.1).


All three of these algorithms accept input of arbitrary length and result in output that may be used to assert message integrity.
Is there a cryptographic taxonomy that best captures this single overarching concept?
The best I could think of so far is each concept can be called a "Transformation" or a "Transformer", but that name is a general purpose alias for simply a function and doesn't represent the "arbitrary length input to output usable for integrity verification" concept. "IntegrityTransformation" could work, but it's not obvious to me if there's a better taxonomy.
As for the output, is there valid synonym for 'hash', 'mac', and 'signature' other than the generic mathematical terms of 'image' or 'output'? Does 'tag' conflict with any of these?
I understand the best answer may be "there isn't one that's regularly used by mathematicians and cryptographers so use whatever makes sense", but I'd like to at least have something that reflects these concepts as intuitively as possible.

On the contrary to your request, In cryptography the devil in details we like to separate the ideas. Yes, all of them can be used for integrity, however, they are not equal.

@kelalaka They're obviously not equal.  In software design, why you choose a crypto algorithm is an orthogonal concern to how you use its corresponding API in code. The latter does not need to be unnecessarily obtuse. Having a (valid, non-superficial) shared taxonomy - if one exists - only enables an API to be simpler, more intuitive, and reinforces SOLID design principles for clean code.
